# Finding CDF for PDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

¡bom dia!

I need to find the CDF for the following:

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases}
6(1-x^2), & -1<x<0, \\ 6/x^2, & 1<x<2, \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases} $$

This is more complex than my previous encounters. Could anyone help me get this started?

I like the layout here! ^_^

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange

Answer (score 1):

Hint : You have to calculate the integral over $f(x)$ from $-1$ to $t$ to get a function $g(t)$. This is the CDF.

The antiderivates are $6x-2x^3$ and $-\frac{6}{x}$

Comment: Note, that $f(x)$ is $0$ in the interval [0,1].

Comment: Is my answer above on the right track?

Comment: For $-1<t<0$, we get $6t-2t^3+4$

Comment: Hmm, I guess I need to spend more time with it. I've been working on this one for a few hours, and I'm just very confused by it.

Comment: For $1<t<2$ , we get $-\frac{6}{t}+10$

Comment: Please check, if $f(x)$ is defined right! The CDF at $x=2$ should be $1$ , not $7$.

Comment: But the normalization is easy, simply divide the values I mentioned by $7$.

Comment: I re-checked the pdf, it was given with c instead of 6. I got 6 for it, and i'm almost 100% sure I did that right.
But i've never done normalization, so i don't know why that would be assigned without it being introduced

Answer (score 0):

Your CDF $F(t)$ will be equal to the integral of your PDF. 
Let's start with $t<-1$ then $F(t)=0$. Then for $t>2$ your CDF is $F(t)=1$.
Now let's say I take $t \in [-1,0]$ then $F(t) = \int_{-1}^t \! f(x) \mathrm{d}\,x = \int_{-1}^t \! 6(1-x^2) \mathrm{d}\,x = 4+6t-2t^3$. Then, finally if $t \in [1,2]$ we need to take another integral: $F(t) = 4+6t-2t^3 + \int_1^t \frac{6}{x^2} \, \mathrm{d} x = 4+6t-2t^3+6-\frac{6}{t}$. Therefore, the final answer is:
\begin{equation}
F(x) = 
\begin{cases}
0, \text{ if } x<-1 \\
4+6x-2x^3, \text{ if } x \in [-1,1]\\
14-\frac{6}{t} \text{ if } x \in [1,2] \\
1, \text{ if } x>2
\end{cases}
\end{equation} 
Your PDF is not normalised, that is why $F(2) \neq 1$. You should check your PDF.

Comment: This is what I am getting now too. But why is F(2) = 3 in this case? Shouldn't it be = 1?

Comment: @IreneRamoa seems like your PDF is not normalised. It should be $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x) \mathrm{d} x = 1$, but in your case it is not true (unless I did some mistake). That is why I got such a strange CDF. However, if you fix PDF problem, then you can follow my steps and get the proper CDF.