# Find CDF when knowing PDF, also find E[X]

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

i lose my login information and have to make new account
i apologies for my poor english

i am given a problem as such:

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases}
c(1-x^2), & -1<x<0, \\ c/x^2, & 1<x<2, \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$

first step is to find c

I calculate c = 6 by following:

$$ \int^0_{-1} c(1-x^2) \, dx + \int^2_1 \frac{c}{x^2} \, dx = 1 $$

is this correct?

2 more part to the problem which trouble me

find CDF $$ F(X) = ? $$

find E(X) 
$$ E(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x)dx $$

i am trouble by the f(x) not being continue from 0, 1 
this is a new problem sort to me

to the one who helps me i am very thankful

Comment: No, $\displaystyle c=\frac{6}{7}$

Answer (score 1):

You calculated $c$ wrong. It should be $c = \frac{6}{7}$ and then according to:
[Finding CDF for PDF](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1054692/finding-cdf-for-pdf/1054735?noredirect=1#comment2147632_1054735)
You will get the following CDF:
\begin{equation}
F(x) = 
\begin{cases}
0, \text{ if } x<-1 \\
\frac{1}{7} \left(4+6t-2t^3 \right), \text{ if } x \in [-1,0]\\
\frac{4}{7}, \text{ if } x \in [0,1] \\
\frac{4}{7}+\frac{6}{7} \left(1-\frac{1}{t} \right) \text{ if } x \in [1,2] \\
1, \text{ if } x>2
\end{cases}
\end{equation} 
For expectation, you should split your integral in the same way.
$$\mathrm{E}\, [X] = \int_{-1}^0 \frac{6}{7} x (1-x^2) \, \mathrm{d} \, x + \int_1^2 \frac{6}{7x} \, \mathrm{d} x = \frac{6}{7} \ln{2} - \frac{3}{14}$$
I hope I didn't do a mistake in expectation.

Comment: how can this be? this gives F(0.999) = 1.14 which > 1?

Comment: @chinpi sure, made some correction

Comment: $E[x]$ is wrong. Please note that the upper bound on the first integral to calculate $E[x]$ should be $0$ instead of $1$.

Comment: @Mehdi sure, let me correct this

Comment: this is now correct, and i am happy 
i thank you kindly